# Did oDesk stop accepting debit card?

Tags: odesk

My debit card doesn't seem to be accepted anymore:

[image]

Did oDesk stop accepting debit card and just take credit cards now?

Comment: This really is rather something you should be asking oDesk.

Comment: @AlE. I sure did but no reply so I'm looking for oDesk users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon contacting Odesk, this was just a bug on their side.